# Python scraping data from asp

Tags: python, selenium, screen-scraping, urllib2, urllib

Alright, I've created a script that enters [this local site](http://www.stf.jus.br/portal/processo/listarOrigem.asp) and searches for a specific "Numero de Origem", a simple integer. However, that required clicking my way through a drop-down menu, typing the number and getting the results on that same page (no redirects or search-specific urls).

With all that in mind, I used [Selenium](http://www.seleniumhq.org/) and the script works fine.

Now I'm trying to run that script on a server. Unfortunatelly, the server does not support Selenium, neither BeautifulSoup or even requests.

Is there a way to make this work while using only urllib or urllib2? [Here](http://support.hostgator.com/articles/hosting-guide/hardware-software/python-modules) is a link of supported python modules, just in case.

Thanks, guys! Really appreciate any help!

Comment: Can you create a python virtual environment on that server, where you could install whatever packages you want?

Comment: Tried that extensively! It worked to some extent: I was able to install selenium and install python 2.7.13, but PhantomJS hangs on get(url) method. It's independent of url and I can wget all of them. Tried Firefox, but same happens. Any hints?